# Schlick's approximation in Blender?

Tags: shaders, source-code

Is it just me or is there really no Schlick's approximation in Blender?

I know that building such a node with the available vector math nodes isn't terribly difficult, but there is no way that Blender only has the standard fresnel node with the ior available right?
What makes me ask this question is this piece of code: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/intern/cycles/kernel/closure/bsdf_util.h#L130
which hints a at a function that might be Schlick's approximation in line 130.

Comment: That function is called from the Principled Shader during sheen and diffuse calculations.  But it's not exposed as a separate function or in a node.  [This search](https://github.com/blender/blender/search?q=schlick_fresnel) returns all of the references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function is called from the Principled Shader during sheen and diffuse calculations. But it's not exposed as a separate function or in a node. [This search](https://github.com/blender/blender/search?q=schlick_fresnel) returns all of the references to the function in the source.

There's no other Schlick calculation as far as I can tell.

Comment: So does this mean that the Principled bsdf uses the Schlick approximation?

Comment: It does, but only for sheen and diffuse.  I didn't look to see what it does for the other places it uses Fresnel.

Comment: Ok that is indeed very strange

Comment: Have you read the original Disney [paper](https://media.disneyanimation.com/uploads/production/publication_asset/48/asset/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v3.pdf)?  There's a lot of ad-hoc magic under the covers.  They weren't really looking for accurate physics so much as good-enough easy-to-use approximation.

Comment: Well to my knowledge disney exclusively used the schlick approximation as it is both cheap to compute, fairly accurate and artist friendly. Now it doesn't really make such a big difference whether you use the schlick approximation or the original fresnel equations, except that the latter is much more expensive to compute and requires a understanding of the complex refractive index. However using one for the specular reflection and another for the diffuse reflection means that the specular tradeoff would not add up to one, which phyiscally speaking wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Well, I may have misspoken.  I meant to say I know it does so for sheen and diffuse but I don't know what it does otherwise because I didn't look.  I didn't mean to say that I know it doesn't otherwise.  And I just reread the Fresnel bits of the Disney paper and they do use Schlick everywhere.

Comment: Ok so the principled probably also does that.

Comment: Well further testing has concluded: the fresnel calculations of the Principled BSDF are more intricate than meets the eye. First: for specular reflection testing has concluded that it probably actually uses the original Fresnel equations with an constant IOR value of 1.5 if the specular value is set to 0.5. Second: The specular value influences the Fresnel equations for both metals and dielectrics. I think that at least for specular reflection it is the specular value, which can be converted to an IOR value, that drives the Fresnel equations and not the base colors as is the case for schlick's

Comment: approximation, but if the metal parameter is 1, it somehow remaps the reflectivity curses so that F(0) does match the base color. Do you have further information on this topic?